# Linux: SSD TRIM for other partitions

Tags: linux, ssd, trim

I have SSD with Linux installed, with two ext4 partitions.
The first one is the mount point `/`. It's trimmed periodically via `fstrim /`.

The other partition is rarely mounted, and used as media storage.

My question is, do I have to run TRIM on the other partition when it is mounted ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could mount with the `discard` option, this will do trimming automatically.

#### Edit

If your partition isn't mounted often and doesn't undergo heavy usage, `discard` may be the best option. Otherwise not doing `fstrim` won't break the device, but it will speed it up if it is used every so often.

Comment: But `discard` is not recommended over `fstrim`.

Comment: Well if you don't want to use it, yes it would be a good idea to occasionally run it on your other partition when it is mounted.